# What is the purpose of the tracer method in Python's turtle?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

```
from turtle import Screen

screen = Screen()

screen.tracer()  # What does this tracer method do? How does it work?
```

It was not understandable in the Python turtle documentation.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you do not understand the documentation, and you cannot explain **why** you do not understand the documentation, then how are we supposed to know what to tell you instead? Please read [ask] and make sure you understand that this is *not a discussion forum*. It is not our goal to re-explain things that have already been explained. Did you try using the example code in the documentation? Do you see how the result is different, if you don't use the `tracer` call?

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.tracer) has some sample code which you could run and play around with, in order to see how `tracer()` affects things. You could try removing it from the code and seeing what happens, or changing the arguments' values.